# PHPExcel как сохранить файл xlsx через браузер?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpexcel

Работаю в PHPExcel и никак не могу сделать сохранение файла в браузере.
Т.е. я обрабатываю файл, в php у меня есть

```
 <a href="Load.php" class="button24">Сформировать отчет</a>
```

А вот файл load.php (Взял из примера PHPExcel)

```
<?php 
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Файл называется simple.xlsx, тот который надо скачать через браузер.

Он сформирован нормально и т.п.

При попытке запустить - выводит иероглифы типа

```
PK�zM!��d�� [Content_Types].xml͖_O�0���...
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вообще сохранять файл через браузер в PHPExcel?

Comment: вы, надеюсь, знаете, что phpexcel уже давно не поддерживается и устарел. И что на домашней странице проекта есть ссылка на актуальную версию?

Comment: n.osennij Да, я это прекрасно знаю, спасибо, но Ваш комментарий никак не помогает решить проблему.

Comment: а где код того, как вы отдаёте пользователю файл?

Comment: Вот как раз с этим у меня проблемы. Смотрите, я сохраняю файл на сервере 
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($Excel);
$objWriter->save('simple.xlsx');
В директорию, которую прописал в open_basedir в php.ini.
Сам файл сохраняется, все ок. А вот вывести на скачивание через браузер никак не выходит. 
Не подскажете в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: так а как вы сейчас его выводите на скачивание? Банально выдайте html ссылку `<a>` на файл c атрибутом `download`

Comment: Подскажите по предыдущей переписке, как решилась эта ошибка. Я в данный момент столкнулся с абсолютно такой же проблемой. Excel-файл сохраняется на сервере, но в браузер (для скачивания) не выводится. В консоль выводятся иероглифы. Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Код правильный. Посмотрите в браузере через инструменты разработчика действительно ли ответ приходит с указанными заголовками. Есть подозрение, что что-то на вашем сайте меняет заголовки ответа

Answer (score 1):

Я для скачивания в браузере использую такой трюк:
На сервере:

```
echo '<a id="download_xls" href="'.$arResult['FILE']['SRC'].'" download="'.$arResult['FILE']['ORIGINAL_NAME'].'"></a>';
```

На клиенте:

```
$.ajax({
    url,
    method: 'POST',
    data,
    success: function (data) {
        $('#downloaded-files').html(data);
        $('#downloaded-files a').each(function () {
            this.click();
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1. Попробуйте сохранить сначала на сервере. Возможно файл "бьётся" на моменте скачивания

Вот часть кода из старого проекта, где все работает.

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($pExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('files/'.$_SESSION['session_username'] . date('His') .'simple.xlsx');
```

Вариант 2. Перед сохранением вызовите `ob_end_clean()`

Вариант 3. Проблема в кодировке. Сохраните файл в UTF-8 with BOM либо просто UTF-8

Comment: На сервере он формируется и сохраняется корректно, а вот вывести на скачиваение из браузера не получается.

Comment: @Denisxyz обновил ответ